# Show $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{z}$ if $z \neq 0$, $f'(0)$ if $z=0$ is holomorphic on unit disk.

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to show that $g(z)=f(z)/z, z\neq 0$ $f'(0), z=0$ is holomorphic if $f(0)=0$ and $f$ is holomorphic on the unit disk.  Here is what I have written but I don't feel its correct;

By the quotient rule, we need only check at $z=0$. We have:

$$g'(0)=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(z)/z-f'(0)}{z}=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac {f(z)/z-\lim f(y)/y}{z}=\frac{\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}f(z)/z-\lim_{y \rightarrow 0}f(y)/y}{\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}z}=\frac{0}{\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}z}=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}0/z$$

But should g'(0) not depend on f? This feels wrong.

EDIT: Just realized this is wrong since I can't split the limit into the quotient (downstairs goes to zero), so I have no idea.

Comment: You can't distribute "$\lim$" at the third equality, since both the denominator and the numerator have limit $0$, the same as what forces us to use L'Hospital's law.

Comment: Yes, that's embarrassing.  So I'm stuck at the second equal sign then.

Comment: I think Cauchy's integral formula can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is holomorphic, it is analytic. So, near $0$, you have$$f(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\cdots$$where $(\forall n\in\Bbb Z_+):a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$; in particular, $a_1=f'(0)$. And so, near $0$,$$g(z)=a_1+a_2z+a_3z^2+\cdots$$and it follows from this that $g$ is holomorphic.

Comment: It's a duplicate, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a classical sketch of the proof (different from the other answer):

1. Let $\Omega \subset \Bbb C$ and $x_0 \in \Omega$. Show that if $f\colon \Omega \to \Bbb C$ is continuous, and if its restriction to $\Omega \setminus\{x_0\}$ is holomorphic, then $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$. This relies on the characterisation of holomorphic functions by the fact that $\int_T f(z)dz = 0$ for any triangle $T\subset \Omega$. (Morera's Theorem)
2. Apply the previous to $g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{z}$ is $z\neq 0$, $f'(0)$ if $z=0$.